# How to calculate poisson kernel density estimation and p value calculation for given distribution?

Tags: python, poisson, estimation, kernel-density

In python, given the distribution (expectedValues), gaussian kernel estimation and p value calculation is provided as follows:

```
kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(expectedValues)
kdePValue = kde.pdf(observedValue)
```

My question: Is there a way to calculate poisson kernel density estimation for given distribution (expectedValues) and p value calculation for a given observedValue in python?

Comment: are you sure you want that?  that's not really a "p-value" as you'd get back from any statistical test; that's just the probability density function (from the estimated kernel) evaluated at your `observedValue`.

Comment: I'd naively estimate an equivalent "p value" for a discrete distribution as just `sum(v == observedValue for v in expectedValues) / len(expectedValues)`

Comment: Thanks @SamMason

Comment: The problem I see here, is that if p-value is small (usual case) then it's integration follows from the tail of the distribution, which may strongly depend on the bandwidth of the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I computed the probability as follows:
I calculated the mean of expected values and give this mean value to the poisson.pmf by importing scipy.stats

```
                mu = sum(expectedValues)/len(expectedValues)
                prob = poisson.pmf(observedValue, mu)
```

Comment: depending on where the data comes from, you might be better off with a longer tailed distribution like a negative binomial.  e.g. `nbinom.pmf(observedValue, size, size/(size+mu))`.  the distribution approaches Poisson as size approaches `+Inf`, but you try starting with, e.g. 10 or 100.